# Automatically visiting all links that a given email address receives in Thunderbid

Tags: thunderbird

When registering in forum the forum usually sends you a verification email. Is there a way to configure Thunderbird to visit all links that a specific email address receives automatically and process relevant Javascript to indicate that the email address is real?

Comment: Mmmm. And what if at the bottom of that mail is a link to unsubscribe from the mailing-list? I have seen this in verification-mails. There could also be a link to state you didn't sign up. Anyway, you can't configure Thunderbird to do this. You would have to use plugins. That plugin would need top load the page, fill in possible additional fields, fill in any caption if present and press ok. (I'm not aware of the existence of any such plugins)

Comment: @Rik: I would count installing a plugin as configurating for my purposes.